# Buscar datos en Sql y mostrarlos en ComboBox de C#

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

Buenas tardes.

Quisiera saber como puedo mostrar datos en un `ComboBox`. Estos datos yo los busco en SQL y los muestro en un `DataGridView` pero quisiera mostralo en un `ComboBox`, esto es lo que tengo de código.

```
public DataTable heater()
    {
        //conectar con la base de datos para extraer el hater segun el manufacturing order que le corresponda
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consql);
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT 
        spmh.[Samtec_Part_Master_Description] 
        FROM[production].[Pockets].[PocketHeater] as ph 
        inner join[production].[dbo].[SAMTEC_PART_MASTER] as spm 
        on ph.[PocketPartNumberId] = spm.[Samtec_Part_Master_ID] 
        inner join[production].[dbo].[SAMTEC_PART_MASTER] as spmh 
        on ph.[HeaterPartNumberId] = spmh.[Samtec_Part_Master_ID] 
        WHERE spm.[Samtec_Part_Master_Description] = '" + extraer() + "' 
        or spm.[Samtec_Part_Master_Description] = '" + prt + "' ", con);

        da.Fill(ds);

        dt = ds.Tables[0];

        return dt;
    }
```

y este es mi formaplication.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 private void txtbuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clas.ordr = txtorder.Text;
        clas.prt = txtpart.Text;

        txtorder.Text = clas.limpio();
        txtpart.Text = clas.extraer();

        //txtheater.Text = clas.heater();
        //lbheaters.Text = clas.heater();
        //upheater.Text = clas.heater();

        cbheater.DataSource = clas.heater();
        dgvheater.DataSource = clas.heater();
    }
```

Y esto es lo que se muestra en el `ComboBox`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: Cual es tu consulta que te va a traer los datos para cargar el `ComboBox`, un `ComboBox` se carga Codigo/Valor, quiero decir `SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories`. Es un ejemplo.

Comment: es un select name, apellido from persona;

Comment: Lo que tu quieres hacer es cargar el `ComboBox`? si es así muestra el método que utilizas para enviarle la colección de datos.

Answer (score 3):

**@use2105** dijo:

> *Quisiera saber como puedo mostrar datos en un ComboBox. Estos datos yo los busco en SQL y los muestro en un DataGridView pero quisiera
>   mostralo en un ComboBox*

Para cargar un `ComboBox` puedes usar `DataTable` o `Listas` fuertemente tipadas para obtener una colección de datos, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
private DataTable CategoryAll()
    {
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()))
        {
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories";
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    var dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Load de tu formulario

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = CategoryAll();
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "CategoryID";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";

    }
```

Demostración:

[image: Cargar de datos ComboBox]

Nota: Es un código de ejemplo que debes adaptarlo a tus necesidades.

**Recomendación:** Al encerrar la declaración del objeto `Connection` entre un bloque `Using` ... `End Using`, nos estaremos asegurando de cerrar la conexión y de destruir los recursos utilizados por el objeto, al finalizar dicho bloque (cuando se ejecute `End Using`). Con ésto no tenemos que estar pendientes de llamar al método `Close` (para cerrar la conexión), ni tampoco al método `Dispose` (para destruir el objeto), por tanto, no es necesario disponer de un procedimiento externo para tales menesteres.

Y en cuanto a llamar al método `Open` para abrir la conexión, no es necesario efectuar dicha llamada si lo que deseamos es rellenar un objeto **`DataTable`**, es decir, cuando llamamos al método `Fill` del objeto `SqlDataAdapter`, porque éste objeto se encargará de hacerlo automáticamente, y de cerrar la conexión cuando finalice su trabajo.

Answer (score 3):

Yo tengo un método para llenar cualquier combo solo pasando parámetros, aquí lo comparto:

```
    public static void LlenarCombo(string query, string displayMember, string valueMember, ComboBox comboBox1, string connectionString1)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString1))
        {
            sqlConnection1.Open();
            DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable();
            using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConnection1))
            {
                sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dataTable1);
                comboBox1.DataSource = dataTable1;
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = displayMember;
                comboBox1.ValueMember = valueMember; //identificador
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1; //opcional
            }
        }
    }
```

Conforme al ejemplo de @pedro-Ávila lo mandas llamar así:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LlenarCombo("SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories","CategoryName","CategoryID",comboBox1, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString());
    }
```

**Nota:** No olviden manejar excepciones, puede un errores de sintaxis en el query, en los campos o de conexión pueden generarlos.